# How can I download files from 'react-native' or 'Expo' to 'icloud drive'?

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, expo

I am trying to create a file and download it to the `device directory`.

I use `react-native-fetch-blob` Also I was used`react-native-fs`

It is easy to download from Android and can check and read files directly from the actual device.

The file I'm talking about is a string file made of json, not a picture or video.

The directory path I use in Android:

```js
const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
dirs.DownloadDir
...
 RNFetchBlob.fs
    .writeFile(path, data, "utf8")
    .then(success => {
      console.log("FILE WRITTEN!");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
```

But the problem is the iPhone. I have already checked the cloud documents and CloudKit through the developer account in Xcode.
[image: ios icloud]

Although it succeeded in using `dirs.DocumentDir` to execute the download, it ran the file app from the actual device and tried to go inside by clicking on `icloud drive` but the file was not visible, just empty.

How can I download to `Icloud Drive`?

Also How do I create a file from 'react-native' to 'On my iPhone' as shown in the picture below?

[image]